# Google couldn't access your site because of a server connectivity error

Tags: google-search-console

I am getting this Error on my new site, How Can i Fix this Issue?[image]

Comment: You don't. These things happen from time to time. As your site is working that is all you can do.

Comment: However, if your server isn't working all the time, improve its reliability or find better hosting.   This error could be because your server went down.   It could also be a network problem anywhere between your site and the Google crawler.

Comment: I recommend that you use Pingdom to track server outrage.